# Harry Potter fanfiction where Harry is taken back in time to witness his younger self being abused

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I don't know if you can help but I'm looking for a fanfic where Harry was heavily abused since he was younger, and he was at Hogwarts (he was older).

Harry had gotten cursed or something and was taken back in time to when he was younger (but he wasn't there, he was just watching). Harry was put in the infirmary and if anyone touched him they would be traveled back with him and also witness it.

I think Sirius, Draco, Snape and others were also there. They had seen Harry's life since he was maybe like three, and witnessed his entire life as it kept jumping to different moments in his life.

Comment: Great first question, welcome to the site! Many members here are brilliant at hunting down story-identification questions. Can you remember anymore details? Perhaps when you read this fanfic/when you think it was published? Include as many details as possible and you're more likely to help another user to find what you're looking for, really add as much as you can remember with the edit button. I hope someone finds it for you! Don't forget that if you happen to find it yourself, you can answer your own question and help people in the future with the same query.